# Как лучше сделать появление скрытой кнопки через чекбокс?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, hidden

Нужно что бы при нажатии на чекбокс появилась кнопка (которая будет удалять поля выделенные чекбоксами),а если галочку снять опять исчезла. Это лучше с помощью чего делать ? JQuery ?

Answer (score 4):

Сразу, пока никто не успел, напишу на *CSS*

```css
button {
  display: none
}

input:checked~button {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<button>кнопка, которая будет удалять поля</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Да. JQuery. Например так:

```
 <button id="btn" class="hidden">Кнопка</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#checkbox').change(function(){
  if($('#btn').hasClass('hidden')) {
    $('#btn').removeClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

Это очень грубый пример. Показывает только пример данной реализации. На деле нужно сделать проверку состояния выбранного чекбокса и отображать кнопку только если чекбокс "чекнут". Так же можно не использовать класс "hidden", а просто воспользоваться jquery командами `show() / hide()`.

Answer (score 0):

да и на ванилле несложно

```
<div>A: <input type="checkbox"></div>
<div>B: <input type="checkbox"></div>
<div>C: <input type="checkbox"></div>
<button>clear</button>

var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.onclick = function(){
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
  for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].checked = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $checkboxes = $('input');
var $button = $('button').hide();

$checkboxes.change(function() {
  $button.toggle($checkboxes.is(':checked'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<button>Кнопка</button>
```

Comment: Это выглядит как проблема jquery а не сниппета...

Comment: Надо просто не оставлять элементы скрытыми по умолчанию. Заодно это может помочь сайту работать при отключенном js.